# Displaying data obtained by cursor in textview in android.

Tags: android, textview

I want to display the value of certain column in database in a TextView.
I have written following code.
But it isn't running after Log.e("problem","here")in LoadEmployee method.
please help

**Code**

```
public Cursor getTestData(String d) 

     { 

         try 
         {   
             String sql ="SELECT name FROM master WHERE sc =' "+ d +" '"; 


             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null); 

             mCur.moveToFirst();

             if (mCur!=null) 
             {  
                mCur.moveToNext(); 
             } 

             return mCur; 


         } 

         catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
         { 
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
             throw mSQLException; 
         }



public void LoadEmployee(View v)

    {


         TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);         
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
        mDbHelper.open(); 
        String d = info_sc.getText().toString();

        Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.getTestData(d); 

         testdata.moveToNext();

         Log.e("problem", "here");
        String title = testdata.getString(testdata.getColumnIndex("name"));

        info_bk.setText(title);

        mDbHelper.close();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: then where is the problem?

Comment: One of your problems here is that you call moveToNext twice on that cursor.. once in the getTestData method and second right after you call that method.. if that is not the issue, please give us more details

Comment: It is giving cursor Indexoutofbound error